# mongodb insert into array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to find the element by id, then go into the array of objects, find the desired by id and add the field guessId into it and insert the id key into it and assign the array of id. How can I do that ?

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=442f1dae0b2d4997ac69d44614e55aa6

In general, I need to create a GuessId field with such a structure

[image]

in fact, I am doing the voting, that is, the key in guessId will be go to vote, and the array to it, this is users who vote

[image]

```
{
  "_id": "f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225",
  "bio": {
    "firstname": "Лена",
    "lastname": "фыв",
    "middlename": "",
    "company": "вв"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "_id": "2e4e40c7-4df6-4974-8d16-bb24cd8134d6",
      "destination": "./uploads/f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225",
      "filename": "2e4e40c7-4df6-4974-8d16-bb24cd8134d6.mp3",
      "path": "uploads\\f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225\\2e4e40c7-4df6-4974-8d16-bb24cd8134d6.mp3",
      "folder": "f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225",
      "info": {
        "size": 20805727,
        "mimetype": "audio/mp3",
        "encoding": "7bit",
        "originalname": "Ахуевший Ленусик (Банк русский стандарт). Выпуск #5..mp3",
        "fieldname": "selectedFile"
      },
      "userId": "5e05da745b21e61ccc84a892",
      "date": "2019-12-27T10:19:12.213Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "81b94dea-ece6-421c-b68a-0aa59332cd0d",
      "destination": "./uploads/f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225",
      "filename": "81b94dea-ece6-421c-b68a-0aa59332cd0d.mp3",
      "path": "uploads\\f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225\\81b94dea-ece6-421c-b68a-0aa59332cd0d.mp3",
      "folder": "f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225",
      "info": {
        "size": 13515683,
        "mimetype": "audio/mp3",
        "encoding": "7bit",
        "originalname": "Выпуск #75 Попрошайка НСВ..mp3",
        "fieldname": "selectedFile"
      },
      "userId": "5e05da745b21e61ccc84a892",
      "date": "2019-12-27T10:25:37.710Z"
    }
  ],
  "date": "2019-12-27T10:19:12.213Z",
  "__v": 1
}
```

Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const HabalkaSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String
  },
  bio: {
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    middlename: String,
    company: String
  },
  files: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: String
      },
      destination: {
        type: String
      },
      filename: {
        type: String
      },
      path: {
        type: String
      },
      folder: {
        type: String
      },
      info: {
        size: {
          type: Number
        },
        mimetype: {
          type: String
        },
        encoding: {
          type: String
        },
        originalname: {
          type: String
        },
        fieldname: {
          type: String
        },
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
      bio: {
        type: Object
      },
      userId: String,
      guessId: {},
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
module.exports = Habalka = mongoose.model('habalka', HabalkaSchema);
```

Comment: Please share collection at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Please copy paste your sample document into the question as text, and try to better explain what you want to do.

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar better to share sample document inside the question.

Comment: check again question please

Comment: Also we need to see mongoose schema for this collection

Comment: I added, sorry.

Comment: I added an answer, can you check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator like this:

```js
router.put("/habalka/:id/:fileId/:guessId", async (req, res) => {

  const result = await Habalka.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: req.params.id,
      "files._id": req.params.fileId
    },
    {
      "files.$.guessId": {
        [req.params.guessId]: ["a", "b"] //todo: get this array from req.body
      }
    },
    {
      new: true
    }
  );

  res.send(result);
});
```

Route url:   `http://..../habalka/f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225/2e4e40c7-4df6-4974-8d16-bb24cd8134d6/asda2`

This will give you a result like this in the given file:

```
    "files": [
        {
            "info": {
                "size": 20805727,
                "mimetype": "audio/mp3",
                "encoding": "7bit",
                "originalname": "Ахуевший Ленусик (Банк русский стандарт). Выпуск #5..mp3",
                "fieldname": "selectedFile"
            },
            "date": "2019-12-27T10:19:12.213Z",
            "_id": "2e4e40c7-4df6-4974-8d16-bb24cd8134d6",
            "destination": "./uploads/f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225",
            "filename": "2e4e40c7-4df6-4974-8d16-bb24cd8134d6.mp3",
            "path": "uploads\\f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225\\2e4e40c7-4df6-4974-8d16-bb24cd8134d6.mp3",
            "folder": "f58482b1-ae3a-4d8a-b53b-ede80fe1e225",
            "userId": "5e05da745b21e61ccc84a892",
            "guessId": {
                "asda2": [
                    "a",
                    "b"
                ]
            }
        },
```

And later if you want to add an item inside one of the guessId arrays, you can use the following code:

```
router.put("/habalka/:id/:fileId/:guessId", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Habalka.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: req.params.id,
      "files._id": req.params.fileId
    },
    { $push: { [`files.$.guessId.${req.params.guessId}`]: "c" } },
    {
      new: true
    }
  );

  res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: can you tell how instead of inserting an array ["a", "b"] to do push "a" in array ?

Comment: @СтасРябцев  please check the updated answer, at the end I show how to do it.